# Making "close to" the same as "equal" in a join

Tags: sql, db2

I am using DB2 in this case, but I'm figuring this has a generic SQL answer.  I have simplified the data as much as I can. I am counting actions on things called "Claims".  Each claim has a unique claim number.  Each action is timestamped in the format "hhmm".  Actually, I'm not counting actions, I'm counting action sessions--Most of the time, a person performs one action on one claim, and that's one action session.  But sometimes a person performs multiple actions on one claim, separated by a few seconds or a few minutes: that also would be one action session.  But if somebody performed an action on a claim at 10am, and then performed an action on that same claim at 1pm, those would be two action sessions.  For my purposes, the time window for what makes something one action session vs. two action sessions is 3 hours, but that's arbitrary, of course. And there is no worry of the window spanning across midnight.  Also, I have read-only access to this data, and I have to do this in one statement.  Thanks.

So Here's some data (Table: ACTIONS):

```
CLAIM_NO ACTTIME
AA       1424
BB       1134
CC       1221
DD       1425
DD       1512
EE       1619
FF       0928
FF       1518
GG       1348
HH       1332
II       1350
```

I would like to turn that into

```
CLAIM_NO ACTTIME
AA       1424
BB       1134
CC       1221
DD       1425
EE       1619
FF       0928
FF       1518
GG       1348
HH       1332
II       1350
```

(Note that the second DD record is gone, but the second FF record is still there).

I have accomplished this by joining the table to itself, on CLAIM_NO being equal and ACTTIME being between 3 hours earlier and 1 minute earlier.  This allows me to get the rows that don't belong, and then I use EXCEPT to eliminate them.

```
with excepto as (
 select a.claim_no, b.acttime
 from actions a 
 join actions b
 on a.claim_no=b.claim_no 
  and a.acttime between (b.acttime-300) and (b.acttime-1)
)
select * from actions except select * from excepto
```

But I'd like to do this with one join, so there is no "except" necessary. This is in hopes that performance will be better: my real data has more columns being used by the except and more rows, of course. And that except statement seems to be slowing the query down a whole lot. I'm using a whole lot of temporary tables via the "with" statement, and they seem to be much slower than the sum of their parts.

Comment: Which version of DB2?  Some functions are not available on some versions.  Also, _why_ are you storing time as what appears to be an `int`?  You may do yourself more harm than good in the long run, doing that - change it to a `time` column (and combine it with a date to a `timestamp`, if appropriate).

Comment: My version of DB2 is V6R1 for iSeries, I believe. So LAG and OVER aren't available to me.  I'm storing time as an int because I did not make this schema, somebody else did, and I just have to report on it.

Comment: I've added an answer.  What about if there are additions at least once every three hours?  You're only going to show the first result then.  Also, `OVER()` is available as part of the `ROW_NUMBER()` OLAP function, although you _really_ want an index over whatever you specify as the `ORDER BY` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a little silly for forgetting about this...

You don't need the `except` - there's a join available called `exception` that does exactly what you want (and I've used it heavily):

```
SELECT a.claim_no, a.acttime
FROM actions as a
EXCEPTION JOIN actions as b
ON b.claim_no = a.claim_no
AND b.acttime >= a.acttime - 300
AND b.acttime < a.acttime
```

Gains you a result set of:

```
claim_No     acttime
============================
AA           1,424 
BB           1,134 
CC           1,221 
DD           1,425 
EE           1,619 
FF             928 
FF           1,518 
GG           1,348 
HH           1,332 
II           1,350
```

(unfortunately, this isn't going to cut it for situations where you have somebody making changes at least once every 3 hours - it's only going to show up the first one.  I believe you need something like a 6-way self-join *minimum* to detect the proper entries, and it's convoluted somewhat, too; you may have better luck dealing with this application side)

Comment: This improved performance big-time.  Thanks very much.  Regarding your concerns about getting a perfect result, I fortunately don't need a perfect result (at least not until the people who do the actions figure out how to game the system).  So for now, this is exactly the result that I needed (which I had before), with acceptable performance (which I didn't have before).  And I learned a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming acttime is an integer column:

```
select *
from (
   select claim_no,
          acttime, 
          acttime - lag(acttime, 1, acttime) over (partition by claim_no order by acttime) as diff
   from actions
) t
where diff = 0 or diff > 300
order by claim_no
```

Comment: I'm not the OP, but this won't run on my version of DB2 (V6R1 iSeries)... perhaps you could list the ones it _does_ run on?

Comment: @X-Zero: I tried it on 9.7 LUW. I don't have anything else available to test - but according to the manual it should also work on 9.5 (does work on Oracle, PostgreSQL and Teradata as well)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I am on V6R1 on iSeries, so this doesn't work.  I'm trying to see if I can duplicate it's logic with the older set of commands, though.